# Remove video from canvas after being played - HTML5

Tags: html, video, canvas

I am making a video quiz, with many smaller video clips. I need to remove the video clip from the canvas after it has been played, so I can present the question. Or redirect from from the video to the question.
Does anybody know how this can be done?

```
<body>
    <video id="pixar" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" autoplay ="autoplay" width="800" height="400" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="pixar.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>  
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure. Listen for the event that fires when the video finishes, and when it happens, remove the video element. What have you tried?

Comment: I will definitely try, thank you.

Comment: And of course, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Thank you :) When I have enough reputation, you have my upvote on your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
<script>
var video = document.getElementByID('pixar');

video.onended = function(e) {
  // remove the video and/or redirect
}
</script>
```